Paint peeling after mist coat
We recently had some plastering done after a new gas burner fitted, I am now having all sorts of problems trying to paint it.
We have had the whole house skimmed and I painted it without problem.
This time however I am getting peeling in some areas of where was skimmed.
My method:
Dusted the wall initially and then lightly sanded the area using a 180 sanding block.
Mixed up a mist coat of trade white emulsion and water approx 60/40 split.
Brushed that across the area and left it for 4 hours. Seemed fine so I then did a first coat of dulux emulsion and that’s when I started seeing some patches of peeling.
Having read some others posts it seems the plaster could have been “polished” when plastering, or I could have got the mist coat wrong. So the advice was to sand it back and start again.
This time I using an electric sanding mouse and took it back and started the whole routine again. And have ended up with the same problem!!
It is not everywhere, just in a couple of small areas.
So frustrating - does anyone have some further advice to fix this.

Perhaps 4 hours was not sufficient for proper drying.

Any time I needed to paint drywall or plaster that was skimmed, I just wiped it down with a damp sponge,To remove the surface dust.  Then primed and painted. Never had a problem.
Perhaps your multistep method did not correct the basic problem of removing the dust on the surface.

How did you prime it?

With primer made to be used with the finish paint I chose.
